# Android Tab layout, accepted patterns?

Tags: android, tabs

Im building an app with a tab-layout. And i have some concerns about tab-layout in general.

- Tab tabs in an app the are connected in some way but passing data between them how?
- And if you pass data how tell parent host to switch tab?
- I've read in a couple of places to not use activities in the tabs but instead use layouts. Why not? I see the tabs as a kind of controller for my view and if i use different layouts in same activity for lets say a "list-view" and a "details" view for some model, my activity will be cluttered with logic for both of them.

For now i have two tabs, one list-view tab display a list of items (DUH!), and one filter tab filtering the items with a button to apply the filter. 
When applying the filter i need to filter the items in the list depending on some factor like item title and category. On the button click i send a broadcast intent picked up by the list and tabhost, switching the tab, and changing the list after the filter.

Does this make sense, how do you do it?

//twd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support the latest and greatest android features, check out the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).  It provides navigation tabs now, which was a weak spot in previous versions.  It is very nice, and uses fragments to handle tab content.

If you want a solution that is implemented for prior android versions, check out the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library that provides a backwards-compatible action bar.

As for communication between tabs, they are all within the same Activity, so you can simply communicate through your Activity class.

Comment: +1 for ActionBar, if your developing a new application, you should really consider this control over the TabLayout. Will make it much more easier for Tablet support.

Comment: Will check it out, but as its only Android 3=<(?) the number of compatible devices probably is to few.

Comment: According to the example i can have backwards compability. So thx again.

Comment: The backwards compability was kinda limited, could not get tab navigation to work in the actionbar. So i used http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html and this guide http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

Since action bar isn't necessarily a solution for every situation, let me throw out another option.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html

Its solves a couple key problems:
1) It allows message passing and control via the Fragment infrastructure allowing the FragmentActivity to manage coordination and communication from tab to tab.
2) It integrates a view pager which will handle the fragment switching and updating tab selection for you
3) It gives you all the benefits of using activities without any of the drawbacks. Fragments are basically smaller activity-like segments you can use to implement functionality with a life cycle similar to an activity.

Another benefit is that the compatibility library adds support for fragments going back to android 1.5. You could also support multiple fragments side by side on larger devices to reduce the number of tabs. Pretty neat solution.